# Is my proof of $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$ implies $C\cap D \subseteq A\cap B$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Suppose we want want to prove if $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$ then $C\cap D\subseteq A\cup B$. Is my proof correct?

> If $x\in C$ and $x\in D$, since $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$, it follows that $C\cap D\subseteq A\cap B$.
>
> If $C\cap D\subseteq A\cap B$ and $x\in C$, then ($x\in C\cap D$ and $x\in A\cap B$) or ($x\not\in C\cap D$ and $x\in A\cap B$). Hence $x\in C\cap D$ and $x\in A\cap B$. Hence $x\in C$ and $x\in A$. Therefore $C\subseteq A$.
>
> If $C\cap D\subseteq A\cap B$ and $x\in D$, then ($x\in C\cap D$ and $x\in A\cap B$) or ($x\not\in C\cap D$ and $x\in A\cap B$). Hence $x\in C\cap D$ and $x\in A\cap B$. Hence $x\in B$. Therefore $D\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line, properly edited, suffices.

If $x\in C\cap D$, then $x\in C$ and therefore $x\in A$; moreover $x\in D$ and therefore $x\in B$. Thus $x\in A\cap B$.

This concludes the proof. Nothing more is needed. But you shouldn't jump to conclusions too early: you start with some $x\in C\cap D$ and then it disappears.

Oh, and the implication “if $C\cap D\subseteq A\cap B$ then $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$” is false, so you're better not trying to prove it.

Example: $C=\{1\}$, $D=\{2\}$, $A=\{3\}$, $B=\{4\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Since $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$, we have that $C\cap A = C$ and $D\cap B = D$. Hence we conclude that
\begin{align*}
(C\cap D)\cap(A\cap B) & = (C\cap A)\cap(D\cap B) = C\cap D
\end{align*}
which implies that $C\cap D\subseteq A\cap B$.

Hopefully this helps!